# Protocol in Mule SSL connector

Tags: xml, ssl, mule

I am trying to use cutom protocol with SSL connector available in Mule. I am refering to this mule documentation [Mule SSL reference](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/SSL+and+TLS+Transports+Reference). But when I am trying to add the protocol in the connector it is giving me the below error

```
   cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'tcp:custom-protocol'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssl":protocol-handler}' is expected.
```

This is my connector configuration

```
   <ssl:connector name="SSL__TLS_" validateConnections="false"
   sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0"
  clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0"
 doc:name="SSL (TLS)">
 <ssl:client path="C:\cert\client.cer" storePassword="password1" />
 <ssl:key-store path="C:\cert\keystore.jks" keyPassword="password1"
 storePassword="password1" />
 <ssl:server path="C:\cert\truststore.ts" storePassword="password1" />
 <tcp:custom-protocol rethrowExceptionOnRead="true"
 class="com.mycompany.protocols.CustomProtocol" />
</ssl:connector>
```

and when I added the protocol-handler tag it is still giving me some error saying

```
    Invalid content was found starting with element 'tcp:custom-protocol'. No child element is expected at this point.
```

As far as I read about the protocol-handler I found that it is the package name which contain the protocol classes.

Can any body help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is the order of the elements in the connector, try with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:tcp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp"
    xmlns:ssl="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssl" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:tls="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssl http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssl/current/mule-ssl.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls/3.4/mule-tls.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp/current/mule-tcp.xsd">

    <ssl:connector name="SSL__TLS_" validateConnections="false"
        sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0"
        clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0"
        doc:name="SSL (TLS)">
        <tcp:custom-protocol rethrowExceptionOnRead="true"
            class="com.mycompany.protocols.CustomProtocol" />
        <ssl:client path="C:\cert\client.cer" storePassword="password1" />
        <ssl:key-store path="C:\cert\keystore.jks" keyPassword="password1"
            storePassword="password1" />
        <ssl:server path="C:\cert\truststore.ts" storePassword="password1" />
        <ssl:protocol-handler property="com.mycompany.protocols" />
    </ssl:connector>

    <flow name="mule-sslFlow1" doc:name="mule-sslFlow1">
        <ssl:inbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="80"
            responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SSL (TLS)" exchange-pattern="request-response" />
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Hi Ale, I have added the namespace and schema location. Kindly find my full configuration file @ http://pastebin.com/hY2SydCL . Still I am getting the following error:-  cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'tcp:custom-protocol'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssl":protocol-handler}' is expected. Kindly confirm that what protocol-handler actually means and does it's porition related to protocol tag matters ?

Comment: @Vicky, I've updated my answer, please try with the configuration I've pasted.

Comment: yes you are right. It was the issue with the order. Is there any specific reason for that?